# Can a singleton object have a (thread-safe) method executing in different threads simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

If so, how will different threads share the same instance or chunk of memory that represents the object? Will different threads somehow "copy" the single-instance object method code to be run on its own CPU resources?

EDIT - to clarify this question further:
I understand that different threads can be in the "process" of executing a singleton object's method at the same time, while they might not all be actively executing - they may be waiting to be scheduled for execution by the OS and in various states of execution within the method. This question is specifically for multiple active threads that are executing each on a different processor. Can multiple threads be actively executing the same exact code path (same region of memory) at the same time?

Comment: Threads don't "own" objects (unless you're using `ThreadLocal` or `ThreadStatic`). However, we need to know what you mean by "thread safe"?

Answer (score 0):

> Can a singleton object have a (thread-safe) method executing in different threads simultaneously?

Yes, of course. Note that this is no different from multiple threads running a method on the same non-singleton object instance.

> how will different threads share the same instance or chunk of memory that represents the object?

(Ignoring NUMA and processor caches), the object exists in only one place in memory (hence, it's a singleton) so the different threads are all reading from the same memory addresses.

Now, if the object is immutable (and doesn't have external side-effects, like IO) then that's okay: multiple threads reading from the same memory and never changing it doesn't introduce any problems.

By analogy, this is like having a single (single-sided) piece of paper on a desk and 10 people reading it simultaneously: no problem.

If the object is mutable or (does have external side-effects like IO) then that's a problem :) You need to synchronize each thread's changes otherwise they'll be overwriting each other - this is bad.

Note that in many languages and platforms, like C#/.NET and C++, documentation can often assert or claim that a method is "thread-safe" but this is not necessarily absolutely guaranteed by the runtime (excepting the case where a function is provably "`const`-correct" and has no IO, which is something C++ can do, but C# cannot currently do that).

Note that just because a single method is thread-safe, doesn't mean an entire logical operation (e.g. calling multiple object methods in sequence) is thread-safe; for example, consider an `Dictionary<K,V>`: many threads can simultaneously call `TryGetValue` without issues - but as soon as one thread calls `.Add` then that messes up all of the other threads calling `TryGetValue` (because `Dictionary<K,V>` does not guarantee that `.Add` is atomic and blocks `TryGetValue`, this is why we use `ConcurrentDictionary` which has a different API - or we wrap our logical business/domain operations in `lock` (`Monitor`) statements).

> Will different threads somehow "copy" the single-instance object method code to be run on its own CPU resources?

No.

You can make that happen with `[ThreadLocal]` and `[ThreadStatic]` (and `[AsyncLocal]`) but proponents of functional programming techniques (like myself) will strongly recommend against this for many reasons. If you want a thread to "own" something then pass the object on the stack as a parameter and not inside hidden static state.

(Also note this does not apply to value-types (e.g. `struct`) which are always copied between uses, but I assume you're referring to `class` object instances, fwiw - as .NET discourages using mutable structs anyway).